# How to mock a method called from a subprocess?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, python-unittest, pytest-mock

there is test, for example:

```py
class TestBlaBla(TestCase):
    def test_lala(self):
         output = subprocess.check_output(some_python_script_file, shell=True)
         ...
```

Let's say in "some_python_script_file" there is a function "some_function" that return "string_1". This "string_1" used in other function inside "some_python_script_file".

How to mock "some_function" so that it returns "other_string"?

This method didn't work:

```py
class TestBlaBla(TestCase):
    @mock.patch('some_python_script_file.some_function', mock.MagicMock(return_value="other_string"))
    def test_lala(self):
         output = subprocess.check_output(some_python_script_file, shell=True)
         ...
```

Comment: You can't. But why _are_ you using subprocess just to call a Python function? Seems like it could be imported and called directly.

Comment: This is just simple an example that depicts idea)

Comment: Please provide a concrete example of `some_python_script_file` that illustrates exactly why it isn't feasible to simply import `some_python_script_file` instead of running it as a separate process.

Comment: What is the exact goal of the test? Is it to run `some_python_script_file`, get the output, then use that output in some other part of the test, like some sort of integration test? Or is it to actually test `some_python_script_file` and check its output? Having a subprocess call inside the test seems like a solution to the wrong problem. Either test the functions in `some_python_script_file` directly, or call it but just the final output.

Comment: When you invoke a separate process, it's a completely new runtime where none of your mocks exist.